# Data attribute value on HTML tag is being read as an array rather than a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span tag in my HTML...

```
<span id="span0" data-input="[1, 2, 3]">span tag 0</span>
```

When I read the input attribute with jQuery...

```
inputString = $("#span0").data("input");
```

...the variable `inputString` is an array with the three elements. How can I read the input attribute so that it's stored as the string "[1, 2, 3]", rather than an array?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method as follows:

```
inputString = $("#span0").attr("data-input");
```

---

```js
inputString = $("#span0").attr("data-input");
alert(typeof inputString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span0" data-input="[1, 2, 3]">span tag 0</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try vanilla-js. It's faster, and it doesn't parse strings to arrays atomagically.

For example, use one of those:

```
document.getElementById('span0').dataset.input;
document.getElementById('span0').getAttribute('data-input');
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('span0').dataset.input);
```

```html
<span id="span0" data-input="[1, 2, 3]">span tag 0</span>
```